# Count query in shell

Tags: bash, shell, debian

I have a file with many entries like

```
asd 13
dsa 14
ert 10
ghj 78
... and many entries like this
```

We can consider it to be key and count pair. Key entries are distinct.

I need top 6 Keys and their count.

WHAT HAVE I DONE: I dont know how to sort it on the basis of count. If I can get to that, I can print top 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sort -nrk2 | head -6
```

- numeric sort
- reverse sort
- sort by field 2
- get top 6

Answer (score 1):

```
cat c.txt|awk '{print $2" "$1}'|sort -nr|head -6
```

Assuming file name as c.txt